# updating attributes via self._dict__

Tags: python, class

I found in here a suggestion to update by bulk class attributes via self.**dict**.upadte
So I tried

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    def update(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

d = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}

c = test(d)
```

and as well

```
c = test()
c.update(d)
```

But I get the error

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Could anyone tell me why this is not working?
Cheers
C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're not passing the values correctly.

```
c = test(**d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Usage kwargs like this:

```
c = test()
c.update(**d)
```

Answer (score 0):

`test(d)` passes d to the constructor of test as the first positional argument (after the instance variable itself). `test.__init__` doesn't take any positional arguments, only keyword arguments. As others have noted, use `test(**d)`.